# How to connect to a wireless network with different domain credentials

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-configuration

I've recently purchased a new computer, and I'm using it for work. The only issue is the username/password combo I'm logged in with is different to my domain credentials in the office.

Now I've managed to set my domain credentials to connect to most domain resources, by adding them to the Windows 8 credential manager with a * wildcard. But when trying to connect to the wireless network (which is secured via domain credentials), I am unable to connect as it's sending my *other* user/pass combo.

How can I specify the credentials to use to connect to this wireless network? (There is no prompt for them when trying to connect. It seems to use my currently logged-in user automatically.)